Why specifying type when accessing element of a matrix?
In OpenCV, to access the elements of a cv::Mat defined by
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_8UC1);

We have to do:
mat.at<uchar>(1,2);

To give the uchar information to mat.at() seems redundant to me. Isn't it already encoded in the header of the matrix? Why do we have to provide it?

I agree that API is inconstent. But the other way around, I would have expected something like cv::Mat<uchar> as basic type. Could well be the reason is historic and there is an underlying "C" style api poking through

You don't have to, if you use cv::Mat_<T>. | Having the datatype encoded in the header at runtime is no good when you need that information at compile time.

@PepijnKramer opencv offers the templated cv::Mat_< _Tp >. But cv::Mat is commonly used as well, and in many aspects it is quite modern. They chose to template the at() methods.

@wohlstad Ah ok so it might be more that OP's usage is somewhat inconsistent. Thanks for the feedback ;)

@PepijnKramer OP's usage of cv::Mat is OK (at least the code they posted) - the type is specified with the method template at as it should be, and should match the data type passed to the constructor - CV_8UC1. I agree that using such data types is somewhat C-stylish. But as I mentioned above cv::Mat is quite modern in many other aspects.

I guess most of all I spoke too soon :)

@PepijnKramer it actually prompted me to refine my answer, and add info about cv::Mat_< _Tp > - so it's all for the best ;-)

@wohlstad appreciated!

OP's usage is fine -- cv::Mat are "variant" types, except they don't use the type system to keep track of that. the type is stored in a field, and using at<>() requires the programmer to know the type of data held in the variant. newbies always get tripped up about that, thinking they can plug in random types into the at<...>() call. yes this is a historical matter. someone 25 years ago decided to stay close to the old C API, and that is how the C++ API turned out. to modern C++ fanatics, it's a war crime. that alone makes me appreciate it ;)

short answer, because mat doesn’t know at compile time what kind of objects it is storing. If you find this strange is because it is, it was fashionable around 20 years ago to have this kind of designs in C and C++. If you want a more modern array library, use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/multi_array/ or (my) https://github.com/correaa/boost-multi

@alfC If someone uses cv::Mat, then it's quite likely because they want to use the rest of the OpenCV, where it's a fundamental data type. Most of the time, it will be high-level APIs and explicit access to individual elements using Mat.at<T>() will be uncommon. Doesn't seem like much of a win in that case, especially if you have to constantly adapt the arrays to a Mat (or something compatible with Input/OutputArray) anyway.

@DanMašek, I agree, it is a tarde off . OpenCV is a framework after all, you need to pay a price if you need to do anything that the framework doesn’t offer or controls. And in then other case, you need to pay by adapting a generic solution to use OpenCV features when you need them. The OP seems to be realizing of the complexity price he/she needs to suddenly pay to have element access.

cv::Mat supports storing elements of various types.
Without the template argument for the at methods, the API could not have  defined the return type - it cannot be determined at compile time unless you specify it.
This is why the various at methods are actually method templates, and the template argument dictates their return value.
For example:
 template<typename _Tp>
_Tp & cv::Mat::at(int i0, int i1)   // NOTE: The returned type `_Tp &` 
                                    //       is using the template parameter

A second reason is for validation:
In Debug mode, if you specify the wrong type for at, you will get an assertion failure.
For example, the source code of the method overload mentioned above (at(int i0, int i1)) contains these 2 assertion which are dependant on the type you specify (_Tp):
CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()));
CV_DbgAssert(CV_ELEM_SIZE1(traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) == elemSize1());

However keep in mind that in Release mode there is no validation, for performance reasons (inferred from looking at the source code). Using the wrong type would lead to undefined behavior.
Note:
If you want to avoid having to specify the type for accessing the elements, you can use cv::Mat_<_Tp> class instead of cv::Mat.
cv::Mat_<_Tp> is a class template and so the element type is embedded in the class type.
It has operator() that you can use to access the elements, without specifying the type (because it is taken from the class template argument).
The potential downside is that the type must be specified at compile time (whereas with cv::Mat it can in principle be determined at runtime).
